# Keep group item on top of the ExpandableListView while scrolling

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have ExpandableListView that is constructed of many groups that have one child each of high height. I would like to keep group item visible on the top while scrolling (up or down) as long as the child is partially visible. When the child disappears after scrolling, group item should also start to disappear.

I saw some unanswered questions regarding that problem from 2012. Has anything changed in last 5 years on that matter?

The only workaround that I can think of is tracking currently visible expanded group and add a new view on the top outside of ExpandableListView that will have the same content as group title. Seems like ugly hack and will appreciate any better solutions.